# hipe compile option meaning and where is the native file

Tags: erlang, hipe

When reading rabbitmq's rabbit.erl，it contain hipe compilation related code.

```
hipe_compile() ->
    Count = length(?HIPE_WORTHY),
    io:format("HiPE compiling:  |~s|~n                 |",
              [string:copies("-", Count)]),
    T1 = erlang:now(),
    PidMRefs = [spawn_monitor(fun () -> [begin
                                             {ok, M} = hipe:c(M, [o3]),
                                             io:format("#")
                                         end || M <- Ms]
                              end) ||
                   Ms <- split(?HIPE_WORTHY, ?HIPE_PROCESSES)],
    [receive
         {'DOWN', MRef, process, _, normal} -> ok;
         {'DOWN', MRef, process, _, Reason} -> exit(Reason)
     end || {_Pid, MRef} <- PidMRefs],
    T2 = erlang:now(),
    io:format("|~n~nCompiled ~B modules in ~Bs~n",
              [Count, timer:now_diff(T2, T1) div 1000000]).
```

But there is no explanation about hipe in the erlang's reference doc. What's the meaning of `'o3'`?

```
(emacs@chen-yumatoMacBook-Pro.local)51> hipe:c(xx_reader,[o3]).
{ok,xx_reader}
```

After I use hipe:c as above, No new compiled file can be found the in the pwd() directory?
Where it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`o3` indicates the optimization level used by the compiler. There're also levels `o0`, `o1`, `o2`. Details of the levels are as follows:

```
   o1 = [inline_fp,pmatch,peephole],
   o2 = [icode_range,icode_ssa_const_prop,icode_ssa_copy_prop,icode_type,
         icode_inline_bifs,rtl_lcm,rtl_ssa,rtl_ssa_const_prop,spillmin_color,
         use_indexing,remove_comments,concurrent_comp,binary_opt] ++ o1,
   o3 = [{regalloc,coalescing},icode_range] ++ o2.
```

You can use `hipe:help_option(Option)` to further investigate the meanings of different options. For example,

```
3> hipe:help_option(regalloc).
regalloc - Select register allocation algorithm. Used as {regalloc, METHOD}.
  Currently available methods:
    naive - spills everything (for debugging and testing)
    linear_scan - fast; not so good if few registers available
    graph_color - slow, but gives OK performance
    coalescing - slower, tries hard to use registers
    optimistic - another variant of a coalescing allocator
ok
4> hipe:help_option(icode_range).
icode_range - Performs integer range analysis on the Icode level
ok
```

---

I think HiPE is JIT compilation, just as the one used in Java. The native parts are available only in runtime, so there should be no explicit representation in your file system.

Also, `hipe:c` do require a `.beam` file is present. For example, if you create a `test.erl` with some stuff, and without compiling it to a `.beam` file, call `hipe:c` directly will lead to an error:

```
1> hipe:c(test, [o3]).
<HiPE (v 3.9.3)> EXITED with reason {cant_find_beam_file,test} @hipe:419

=ERROR REPORT==== 29-Nov-2012::17:03:02 ===
<HiPE (v 3.9.3)> Error: [hipe:418]: Cannot find test.beam file.** exception error: {hipe,419,{cant_find_beam_file,test}}
     in function  hipe:beam_file/1 (hipe.erl, line 419)
     in call from hipe:c/2 (hipe.erl, line 313)
2> c(test).
{ok,test}
3> hipe:c(test, [o3]).
{ok,test}
```

Comment: HiPE is not a JIT compiler. The native code is saved as part of the .beam file, so if you have compiled the module to native code once, the native code can be loaded immediately next time. (If you move the .beam file to a different architecture, the native code cannot be used unless you recompile it on the new platform.)

Comment: @RichardC Thanks! Do you have some detail reference for that? And why `hipe:c` requires the `.beam` file is present?

Comment: hipe:c() does not require that the .beam file is present. But normal users should not use the hipe module to compile modules - just give the +native flag to erlc. Also see http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/HiPE_app.html

Answer (score 1):

There is some in erlang's doc. See [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/HiPE_app.html). But the doc is not much indeed. The [index page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/hipe/index.html) of HiPE only updated recently.

Also, you can check some help in erlang shell.

```
> hipe:help().
> hipe:help_options().
> hipe:help_option(Option).
```